# Windows route add error

Tags: windows-server-2003, routing

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>route print

IPv4 Route Table

Interface List 0x1 
........................... MS TCP Loopback interface 0x10003  
...00 14 22 10 7f ea ...... Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection #2 0x10004 
...00 14 22 10 7f e9 ...... Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection

=========================================================================== 
Active Routes:  
Network Destination  Netmask          Gateway         Interface       Metric 
0.0.0.0              0.0.0.0          192.168.12.199  192.168.12.39   10 
127.0.0.0            255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1        1 
192.168.12.0         255.255.255.0    192.168.12.39   192.168.12.39   10 
192.168.12.39        255.255.255.255  127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       10 
192.168.12.255       255.255.255.255  192.168.12.39   192.168.12.39   10 
224.0.0.0            240.0.0.0        192.168.12.39   192.168.12.39   10 
255.255.255.255      255.255.255.255  192.168.12.39   10003            1 
255.255.255.255      255.255.255.255  192.168.12.39   192.168.12.39    1
Default Gateway: 192.168.12.199

Persistent Routes: None

C:\>route -p add x.x.x.x mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.96.199 
The route addition failed: Either the interface index is wrong or the gateway 
does not lie on the same network as the interface. 
Check the IP Address Table for the machine.
```

I can't add the above routing. Why?

Answer (score 1):

*I am assuming x.x.x.x is something you replaced for confidentiality and was a proper IP-address in the original command.*

**192.168.96.199 is on a different network, the gateway must be on the same network.**

Your local netmask is probably correct (mask 255.255.255.0 for subnet 192.168.12.0)

Are your sure the third octet (96 not 12) of your gateway is correct?